# Filtering/Pattern Matching in nested data structure

Tags: list, dictionary, nested, elixir

I am new to Elixir and still very confused with pattern matching.

`[%{name: "Deutschland", code: "DE"}, %{name: "Frankreich", code: "FR"}]`

```
  def find_by_code([], _name), do: []
  def find_by_code([h | t], query) do
    if h[:code] == query do
      IO.puts("MATCH")
      IO.inspect(h)
    else
      IO.puts ("No match")
      find_by_code(t, query)
    end
  end
```

Is that the best way to find the country by code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pattern match as deep as you want:

```
def find_by_code([], _query),
  do: nil # or whatever you want to mean "not found"

def find_by_code([%{code: query} = country|_t], query),
  do: IO.inspect(country)

def find_by_code([_country|t], query),
  do: find_by_code(t, query)
```

You can also use the `Enum.find/3` with `match?/2`, which may be more readable (as suggested in another answer).

Comment: This is a great answer, didn't even know the second form was possible!

Comment: Great answer, one small addition that will get rid of a warning. The `t` variable in the second function clause is not used and hence should be specified as `_t`.

Comment: @b73 good catch! I wrote that on mobile so I didn't even run it, oops :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You could do it this way:

```
countries = [
  %{name: "Deutschland", code: "DE"},
  %{name: "Frankreich", code: "FR"}
]

Enum.find(countries, &match?(%{code: "FR"}, &1))
# %{code: "FR", name: "Frankreich"}
```

Comment: The `match?/2` macro is **nice**! I don't know how I didn't know about that. Thanks Patrick!

Comment: Yes, I was really excited when I found out about it, too! I first [wrote a macro](https://gist.github.com/padde/a759b18bca7851e8ffaa) to do this. Nevertheless, it was my first macro and I learned a lot in the process ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Elixir doesn't have built in pattern matching for trying to filter out certain items of a list based on their values.

You could write a pattern match to check individual items like so:

```
match_country_code = fn (%{:code => "DE"} = country) -> country 
                        (_) -> nil
                     end
```

And then pass that to Enum.find:

```
lands = [
  %{name: "Deutschland", code: "DE"},
  %{name: "Frankreich", code: "FR"}
]
Enum.find(lands, &(match_country_code.(&1)))
# => %{code: "DE", name: "Deutschland"}
```

Or to generalize you could:

```
lands = [
  %{name: "Deutschland", code: "DE"},
  %{name: "Frankreich", code: "FR"}
]

find_by = fn (list, key, val) ->
  Enum.find(list, &(Map.get(&1, key)==val))
end

find_by.(lands, :name, "DE")
#=> %{code: "DE", name: "Deutschland"}
```

Change find to filter and get a list of results:

```
lands = [
  %{name: "Deutschland", code: "DE"},
  %{name: "Germany", code: "DE"},
  %{name: "Frankreich", code: "FR"}
]

filter_by = fn (list, key, val) ->
  Enum.filter(list, &(Map.get(&1, key)==val))
end

filter_by.(lands, :code, "DE")
#=> [%{code: "DE", name: "Deutschland"}, %{code: "DE", name: "Germany"}]
```